# Want blur image once the process is completed in tracking process

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blur

I am creating a website wherein a user is looking at the tracking screen. In this screen the user is able to see the current status of the package. As soon as first process is completed, the completed process then blurred and the current status is glows. Here is the code I have written in HTML and CSS

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.imgage {
  margin-top: 150px;
}

body h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif, 'Montserrat';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="imgage">
      <img src="images/fil_1.jpg" width="202px" height="100px">
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="imgage">
      <img src="images/export1.jpg" width="202px" height="100px">
      <h2>IMPORT</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="imgage">
      <img src="images/UKimport.jpg" width="202px" height="100px">
      <h2>CARRIER</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="imgage">
      <img src="images/DHL.jpg" width="202px" height="100px">
      <h2>DHL</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="imgage">
      <img src="images/HMRC_logo.jpg" width="202px" height="100px">
      <h2>HMRC</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="imgage">
      <img src="images/Importt.jpg" width="202px" height="100px">
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question about this code? Just FYI, your HTML is invalid as you're missing all the `</div>` tags within the `<li>`. Also, it seems a little odd to have multiple `ul` each containing only a single `li`, should they not be grouped together within one `ul`?

Comment: If you're asking how to blur an image using CSS, there are many questions and answers on Stack Overflow covering that topic. [A simple search for "how to blur an image using CSS"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+blur+an+image+using+css) shows 99 results...

Comment: Where is the question??

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best to understand what you wanted to do.

My interpretation is that you wanted to blur the page while things get loaded and then show the loaded page.

I added the code to do that plus I added a code to emulate the photos that were not loading since they were not included with the full URI to reach them.

If by any chance this is not what you wanted, then please edit your question and let me know so I can change my answer to it.

```js
// Emulating loading the photos
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $("#cover").fadeOut(200);
});

function callLoad(){
    $(window).load();
}
setTimeout(callLoad, 1000);

$(function() {
  
  $('.image').each(function(){
    let randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    $(this).attr('src', 'https://picsum.photos/id/' + randomNumber + '/202/100');      
  });    

  var images = $('.image').sort(function (a, b) {
    return +$(a).data('sort') - +$(b).data('sort');
  });
  
  var index = 0;
  var getNextImage = function(index){
    var remainder = index % images.length;
    return $(images[(remainder === 0) ? images.length - 1 : remainder - 1]);
  };
    
  $("#btnNext").click(function(){    
    getNextImage(index - 1).addClass("blur-content");
    getNextImage(index).toggleClass("blur-content");   
    index++;
  });
  
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.imgage {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

body h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif, 'Montserrat';
}

#cover {
  top:0; 
  left: 0;  
  position: fixed; 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  background: #CCC; 
  z-index:9999;
}

.blur-content {
    -webkit-filter: url(#svg-blur);
    filter: url(#svg-blur);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="btnNext"> Next </button>
<div id="cover" class="blur-content"></div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="imgage">
        <img class="image blur-content" src="images/fil_1.jpg" width="202px" height="100px" data-sort="7">
        <h2>SOMETHING</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="imgage">
        <img class="image blur-content" src="images/export1.jpg" width="202px" height="100px" data-sort="2">
        <h2>IMPORT</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="imgage">
        <img class="image blur-content" src="images/UKimport.jpg" width="202px" height="100px" data-sort="3">
        <h2>CARRIER</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="imgage">
        <img class="image blur-content" src="images/DHL.jpg" width="202px" height="100px" data-sort="4">
        <h2>DHL</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="imgage">
        <img class="image blur-content" src="images/HMRC_logo.jpg" width="202px" height="100px" data-sort="5">
        <h2>HMRC</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="imgage">
        <img class="image blur-content" src="images/Importt.jpg" width="202px" height="100px" data-sort="6">
        <h2>HMRC2</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- SVG Blur Filter -->
<!-- 'stdDeviation' is the blur amount applied -->
<svg id="svg-filter-blur">
    <filter id="svg-blur">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

Comment: On clicking an external button, the next "li" element should be selected and the selected "li" should glow and rest others should be blur.

Comment: @xProgram what external button? Let me understand correctly, using a button, you want to go one picture at the time by blurring all of the picture except the one in turn? Is this correct?

Comment: @xProgram, I updated the code based on my new understanding based on your feedback. Take a look.